# Ferramentas para combinação de cores

Tags: combinações, cores

Pessoal estou começando a desenvolver projetos pra Web e uma dificuldade que eu tenho é de associar cores ou combiná-las.

Pensando nisso encontrei uma ferramenta chamada "Adobe Kuler" que me ajuda de vez em quando. Porém gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma outra ferramenta ou até mesmo uma técnica de descobrir que cor combina com determinada cor. Vocês sabe de alguma ferramenta boa para gerar paleta de cores que combinam ou que possa melhorar o trabalho usando cores?

Comment: O que vem a ser precisamente associar cores ou combinar cores? Por exemplo, na opinião do João, azul e vermelho combinam, mas a Maria acha que isso não combina. Já o Pedro tende a associar verde com laranja, mas a Zuleide acha que é melhor associar verde com azul. Enfim, o que exatamente você quer dizer por associar ou combinar cores?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem o [Coolors](http://coolors.co/) ele gera uma paleta de cores automaticamente.

Você pode travar as cores que você gostou é vai mudando as outras.

E também pode salvar sua paleta, publicar, exporta para diferentes tipos de arquivos.